# ipod app replacement-in-a-tab?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

With the new media-library capabilities in the 3.0 SDK, I'd like to have a tab in my application to control the music that's playing. Not just pause and play (i'm aware that pressing the home button twice brings up controls for this), but also the ability to browse and queue albums/artists/songs/playlists. Basically a copy of the ipod app functionality.

Any chance someone has already done this and made it freely available?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any readily available source for you. However, the [Media Player Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/index.html) is pretty straight-forward, and you should be able to mimic the iPod app pretty easily (sans CoverFlow and other niceties, of course). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The Media Player framework gives you very limited access to the iPod music player. For example,  you can't know where the currently playing song is in its playlist. If you use the application music player, it stops the currently playing song, and when you quit, it stops playing, but the app music player does give you more control over playlists.

In short, you can't replicate all the features of the iPod app in a tab in the OS 3.0 through 3.1.3, but you can do a good job of the basic features of the pop-up control when you double-click the home button.